# Median from probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a probability density function:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac 1 4xe^{\frac {-x}2}, & x\ge0 \\ 0, & x < 0\end{cases}$

To add more detail, cdf is:

$F(x) = \begin{cases} 1+\frac{-1}2xe^{\frac {-x}2}-e^{\frac {-x}2}, & x\ge0 \\ 0, & x < 0\end{cases}$

Find the $Med(x)$.

Solving

$$\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x) dx=1+\frac{-1}2xe^{\frac {-x}2}-e^{\frac {-x}2}=\frac 12$$

I found 2 values $3.3567$ and $-1.5361$, and my book said that the answer is $-1.5361$. This is confusing because I thought $Med(X)\ge 0$.

Comment: The median is unique. So you can’t find two values.

Comment: I solve the equation and it gives me 2 $x$ values, I haven't determined which $Med(X)$ is yet.

Comment: Which equation did you solve? Please update the question with what you did.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: You made an error as you have to separate the cases $x<0$ and $x \ge 0$.

Comment: if $x<0$ then $F(x)=c; c=0,1$ ($F$ is cumulative distribution function)

Comment: Only the non-negative solution should be median since you used that part of the cdf for which $x\ge 0$; $F(x)$ cannot be $1/2$ for any $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your PDF is for the distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=2,\text{rate}=\frac 1 2).$
See the relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) page (or your textbook) for details. You seek $F_X^{-1}(\frac 1 2) = 3.356694.$

In R statistical software, the inverse CDF (quantile function)
is denoted `qgamma` with appropriate arguments.

```
qgamma(.5,2,1/2)
[1] 3.356694
```

I agree with the comment of @StubbornAtom, that the median
cannot be negative. The "answer" −1.5361 is simply wrong.

Here is a graph of the PDF, with the location of the median
shown by a dotted red line.

[image]